# Arrgghhhh!! SQLite is enough to try patience of a Saint

Tags: visual-studio-2010, sqlite

I come to you with an achy head.  I've written and used some software (.net 3.5, VS2010) where I added separate (Data) project which accesses a SQLite database.  It's been working PERFECT until tonight!  I don't lie - for absolutely NO REASON whatsoever I've started getting an age old error:

```
Error   4   The type 'System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'System.Data.SQLite, Version=1.0.66.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=db937bc2d44ff139'.    C:\ALL\Dev\Working Dir\BeatBits\BeatBits\MainForm.cs    50  13  BeatBits
```

Does ANYBODY know what this is, why it's suddenly appeared (with no code changes) and more so, how I can FIX this ONCE and FOR ALL?!  :-(

Cheers in advance peoples for your help!

Comment: Did you follow the instructions?

Comment: Yes.  There is a reference to it - v1.0.66.0.  I removed this

Comment: read this? http://sqlite.phxsoftware.com/forums/p/1823/7755.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Thanks guys!
For some read my app had dropped the reference to the .dll.  I re-added it and compiled it, saved it, re-loaded VS2010 and the same again.  I deleted my solution files and re-created them and all OK.  Sorry for my tantrum!! :\ Lol